# How to calculate the number of protons in a sphere given the volume and the pH?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph, concentration

The spherical radius of a nano-droplet of a solution ($\mathrm{pH}$ of which is $6$) is given as $\pu{20nm}$.

I can find the molar concentration of $\ce{H+}$ and subsequently the number of $\ce{H+}$ ions, but I am getting a fractional number ($\approx 2 \times 10^{-2}$). This is obviously wrong as there should be at least $1$ proton in a compartment which has an acidic $\mathrm{pH}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong - it's just that there would be a 2% chance of presence of a single  H3O+ in one of such droplets if you, say, sprayed such solution.

Comment: @Mithoron : But how can the pH of all such droplets be 6 then? Or is it the average pH which is 6?

Comment: 20 nm is so little that pH loses sense, it isn't even a phase, but some nanodroplet. One could say it's average pH if you had mist made of them.

Comment: Chemical equilibriums, similarly as temperature, are statistical thermodynamic properties of large scale systems. They are gradually losing sense for small enough systems. Imagine there is attribute of people with probability 0.01. If there is 10 people and none of them has such an attribute, does it mean it's probability is zero ? Of course not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the concept of pH as a thermodynamic property of nanodroplets does not quite make sense unless the nanodroplets are in equilibrium (stable). If they are in equilibrium you can still apply the equation 
$$\textrm{pH}=-\log_{10}(a_{\ce{H+}})$$ but now you have to be aware that the activity will be influenced by surface (and other) effects and the approximation $$\textrm{pH}=-\log_{10}(c_{\ce{H+}})$$ may not hold. But assume it does. Then as you point out, the average number of hydronium ions per nanodroplet is

$$\begin{align} n_{\ce{H+}} &=\pu{10^{-6} M}\cdot(\frac{4}{3}\pi\times\pu{20^3 nm^3}\times\pu{10^{-27} {(m/nm)^3}}\times\pu{10^3 L/m^3})\times \pu{6.022\times10^{23} mol^{-1}}\\&=0.020 \end{align}$$

Which is ok. That just means that on average only 1 out of 50 nanodroplets contains a solvated proton. Note by the way that one nanodroplet also contains about a million water molecules.

This is a real "rabbit hole" of a question, given all that is not specified, which is why I used sleight-of-hand and wrote that I am ignoring surface effects and assuming the particles are at equilibrium. It doesn't address how to prepare nanodroplets with the desired average proton concentration or what equilibrium means (are nanodroplets exchanging matter or are they isolated?). As noted in comments, composition (buffering molecules if any, salts and other ions including hydroxyl), droplet charge etc, are being ignored and you can expect statistical fluctuations in concentrations between different droplets. However if I stick to the assumption of equilibrium then I can say (for what it's worth) that ~2% of droplets have ~pH 4.3, and most of the rest are at neutral pH.

Comment: "... on average only 1 out of 66 nanodroplets contains a solvated proton" at a given time. If the solution is buffered, the pH will still be 6 as a time-average concentration (or activity) of protons. If the solution is not buffered, a pH of 6 is kind of meaningless even for larger volumes.

Comment: I'd flip that last sentence around. It means that $0.015%$ of the protons have a very low pH and the other $0.9985%$ are just plain water

Comment: @Poutnik I understand the argument, it is not simple. My point is that if you have a thermodynamicaly stable aerosol you can certainly define a temperature, as well  as the average concentration of *anything* in the aerosol. You can have fluctuations between the droplets, of course, but you can (ignoring the strict definition of pH in term of activities) simply express the H+ concentration as pH (as an algebraic manipulation).

Comment: I would rather say pH, similarly as temperature or chemical equilibrium are statistical phenomena of large scale. For small enough scales, all of them do not have sense anymore.For pH, it turns into probability of H3O+ occurence.

Comment: I agree it seems absurd to define a concentration when you only have 1 of something in a volume. Note you have fluctuations within segments in a bulk phase, too. And there is the ergodic principle. The catch is that in the bulk you have material transfer between segments, and surface effects disappear.

Comment: I mean both pH and T have some fuzzy border, below which they do not make sense.  I'd a ddople is so small a H3O+ occurence has probability reaching zero, pH stops making sense in this scale. Similarly, at much smaller scale,temperature stops making sense.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean with "stops making sense". You can still use pH 6 as shorthand for "average activity of H+ in the droplets is $1 \times 10^{-6} M$ - but yes this is not the strict definition of pH for a bulk sample. And yet, would you deny that in a droplet with 1 million water molecules you can define an activity for one H+ ion? All you need to consider is an ensemble of droplets?

Comment: On a nitpicking side, *spherical radius* isn't the same as *radius of a sphere*. The volume of the droplet is going to be even smaller.

Comment: @andselisk Ok, could you clarify that? You mean $V \ne \frac{4 \pi}{3} r^3$?

Comment: @BuckThorn Droplet is not a sphere, it can be envisioned as [a *cap* of the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere) of the radius $r$; so volume of the droplet $V < \frac{4 \pi}{3}r^3$ and depends on the contact angle.

Comment: @andselisk ah, the assumption is that we are dealing with a sphere, but droplets are not usually spheres. Reminds me of [spherical cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow)

Comment: @BuckThorn …in vacuum, yes, but that is exactly what *spherical radius* means. If you ever did an engineering drawing with a round-cap stick, its dimension is described with *spherical radius*.

Comment: @andselisk are you sure you don't mean "circular radius"? I've not seen "spherical radius" used in the context you refer to, or certainly not exclusively (memory might fail).

Comment: @BuckThorn OMG I forgot how you like to play ping-pong in the comments. No, *circular radius* is what you used (considering projection of the sphere a circle), and it's not the same as *spherical radius*. Seriously, have a look at Figure 4 [in this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00223131.2014.873359?needAccess=true&) or just search Google Images with `"spherical radius" droplet`.

Comment: @andselisk yes, I find chat rooms constricting  :-) ping-pong is more for me, allows me freedom to wander. But I don't get it, Figure 4 of the article you linked indicates that spherical radius is.... the radius of a sphere (as I would have expected)? Sure, the sessile water droplet is a slice of that sphere.

Comment: Anyway, I see what you mean, good point. Add that to the list of somewhat ambiguous aspects in the question.